# Error: Found a string attribute with unrecognized format

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

im currently using MSCRM Toolkit for Dynamics 365 and wanted to export Audit reports.
When using the Audit Export Manager
On a CRM Online 2016 Update instance
While executing the "(Re) Load Source Structure" command
the following error message is received:

```
Error: Found a string attribute with unrecognized format.
```

How can i resolve the issue stated above so that i can load the entities, etc. to make audit export possible?
Here is the screenshot of the error, though we put the needed credentials still same error we still get.

[image: Error: Found a string attribute with unrecognized format]

Please help, we have presentation to come hope that professionals in Dynamics365 or those that have answers to my question can help

Answer (score 0):

I came across this with MetadatDiagramConsole.exe as well when trying to pull from Dynamics365 online environment. I found changing  *RetrieveAsIfPublished* to true worked. 
Also the wonderful toolbox team has posted an updated version recently that worked for others trying the audit process you mention. 
https://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/630624